# Bring in/bring out

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs

Is "to bring something with you" the exact meaning of "bring in" at 2:44 and does "bring out" at 2:53 mean to tell someone about something?

https://youtu.be/OuVYb4q3McY

I looked them up in OAD but couldn't find the meanings that would match this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At 2:44, when Butler says, *"Do you mind me bringing this in?"*, he is asking Ferguson if it is OK to talk about the topic (of the card, calling him a "numpty") He is asking if it's OK to **bring** the topic **into** the conversation. An alternative to "bringing this in" could be "introducing this" or even just "mentioning this".

At 2:53, however: well, first, I think Butler might be saying "I had to bring that **up**", not "I had to bring that **out**". Butler is Scottish (as I am), but his accent has been modified by his acting, and probably by being in the US a lot, so the last word isn't exactly clear. (I know that YouTube auto-captioning says "out" but I think it's wrong.)

Anyway, if it's "bring…up" it simply means to "mention", or to "raise" the topic.

If, however, it is indeed "bring…out", it would tend to mean "highlight" or "emphasize". It's partly because that doesn't really make sense in the context that I think he says "up" and not "out". If Butler did say "out" I'd still maintain that he *meant* "up" and that in the fast banter between him and Ferguson he simply stumbled, as we all often do.